# Is it possible to get an <h1> tag to be autofocused?

Tags: javascript, html

Right now my autofocus is on an input that doesn't provide much information for a screenreader... the screenreader would be much better for the visually impaired if it automatically read out the h1 tag on my page. I tried adding an autofocus attribute to my h1 but it didn't do anything. Do I have to do it with javascript?

Comment: How do you add focus to a non-input element?

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to do that (I have the same case as you in a modal) you can add a
`tabindex="-1"` with your `auto focus` like that

`<h1 mat-dialog-title tabindex="-1" autofocus>Modal name</h1>`

The `tabindex` attribute explicitly defines the navigation order for focusable elements (typically links and form controls) within a page. It can also be used to define whether elements should be focusable or not.

[Both] `tabindex="0"` and `tabindex="-1"` have special meaning and provide distinct functionality in HTML. A value of **0** indicates that the element should be placed in the default navigation order. This allows elements that are not natively focusable (such as , , and you understand now ) to receive keyboard focus. Of course one should generally use links and form controls for all interactive elements, but this does allow other elements to be focusable and trigger interaction.

A `tabindex="-1"` value removes the element from the default navigation flow (i.e., a user cannot tab to it), but it allows it to receive programmatic focus, meaning focus can be set to it from a link or with scripting or `autofocus`. This can be very useful for elements that should not be tabbed to, but that may need to have focus set to them. like in your case :)

**More info**: http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar situation, the Adrien Delabie's answer is partially correct but as it notes you have the problem that this removes the h1 from the navigation flow of the document.

That's bad.

Furthermore while giving something a tabindex makes it focusable VoiceOver (at the time of this writing) ignores non natively focusable elements when focused programmatically.

So I make an element like this

```
<h1>{{normalHeader}} <a id="specialfocusable" tabindex="-1">{{focusText}}</a> </h1>
```

Obviously when we decide to focus we focus on the #specialfocusable a element, but first we set the normalHeader to be an empty string and focusText to be the text we want the screen reader to read.

Voiceover reads it, the h1 is still in normal document flow so you can normally tab to it. (I have not had the chance to check in other screenreaders but I believe it shall work, at worst I need to handle a lose focus on the #specialfocusable and set normalHeader back and set focusText to empty string again), the a element is not read unless focus set on it with the focusText.

Of course you should also style the a so it does not look like an a, the same thing would work for any focusable element. Just an a element is the easiest to style.

Answer (score -2):

All else being equal, an `h1` can't be focused at all. It doesn't make sense to focus it anyway: It isn't an interactive element. You don't expect clicking on a heading to do anything (as you would if you clicked on a link, button, or input).

If you don't want the focus to interfere with reading the page in a normal linear fashion: Don't override the focus at all. Then the browser will start at the top of the page.

Comment: What would be the best way to get a screenreader to automatically read the h1 done when you go the page? Change the h1 tag completely to one that can be focused?

Comment: @yxu296 have you found any answer to this?

Comment: you do want to focus to h1, when you change the route on SPA